# How to check if a textbox input contains leading zeros?

Tags: extjs

If someone enters something like '0123', then it will detect the leading zero.
I haven't found anything to check leading zeros.

Comment: What do you want to do if there are leading zeroes - validation error, different code on save/button press, check on entry? This isn't ExtJS specific code - it'll be standard Javascript

Comment: If there are zeros, then a popup message will be displayed and after pressing an "Okay" button, the leading zeros will be removed.

Comment: If there are zeroes after focus leaves the control, after pushing another button, as soon as a key is pressed? When this code is kicked off is the key to where you trigger it from

Answer (score 0):

Trythis

```
listeners:{   
change:function(thisObj,newValue,oldValue,eopts){   
if(newValue===0||newValue==="0"){   
//showmsgandclearfield      
}  
}  
}
```

Comment: I have found this:   `number.startsWith("0")`